# Instantiating an object with the same name as a dynamically generated string in python?

Tags: python

I have an class:

```
class Competitor(object):
      def __init__(self, name):
          self.name = name
```

I have an array of names:

```
names = ["john", "micheal", "adam"]
```

How can I run through this array and instantiate a Competitor with the same name in this array? So at the end I would like Competitor objects john, micheal and adam.

Will this work: trying to create a dict

```
hackers = {}
for name in names:
    hackers[name] = Competitor(name)
```

P.S. I tried looking through other questions but I didn't understand what they were trying to do/ wasn't sure if it was the same problem I had.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Your code /should/ work... that's exactly how you do it.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been quicker to run the code that write up this question?

Comment: Yea, I thought of this while I was typing it out and thought it might help someone in the future. I'm trying it out rn

Comment: yes it worked.  hackers = {}
for name in names:
    hackers[name] = Competitor(name)